# Hide view from Recycler view

Tags: android

I need suggestion,
I am new in android, I am trying to implement emojis like facebook in my feed
using this link
[FBReaction](https://github.com/dbof10/FBReaction) I am able to show the emojis on click of my Like button But I am not able to remove it from my view once the emojis got selected.

Here is my code in Adapter file to show emojis view

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_social, parent, false);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.btReaction);
        final CardView root = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ReactionView rvl = new ReactionView(mContext);
                root.addView(rvl);
            }
        });
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
```

`ReactionView rvl = new ReactionView(mContext);
root.addView(rvl);`

Above line is used to show the emojis view.

`RelativeLayout rl` is my layout on click of this layout I am showing my emojis list. like below

[image]

same as above I have multiple feeds where I have like button, on click of those button I am able to show emojis view but couldn't remove it once it is selected.

I have a different class (`ReactionView`) to show the emojis List which is available in Git Repo

now My problem is how I remove the view once the emojis got selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the custom view `ReactionView` class a little bit, if you notice the `onTouchEvent()` of that class it registers different `MotionEvent`'s, and particularity, when the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` event is triggered, this means that the user has left their finger of the `ReactionView` emojis, at this time you need to remove the `ReactionView` from your layout.

So as you can remove your view when the `onDeselect()` is over, so to that, there is a couple of methods:

**Method 1:**

Remove the focus from the `ReactionView`, and implement `OnFocusChangeListener` on the `ReactionView`

```
public class ReactionView extends View {

    ... 

    private void onDeselect() {
        deselectAnimation.prepare();
        startAnimation(deselectAnimation);

        // Hide the view and remove the focus from it.
        setVisibility(GONE);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        setFocusable(false);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    }
```

In activity

```
rvl.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus)
            root.removeView(rvl);
    }
});
```

**Method 2:**

Create a listener to the `ReactionView`, trigger its callback in `onDeselect()` and implement it on your activity

```
public class ReactionView extends View {

    ... 

    public interface DismissListener {
        void onDismiss();
    }

    public void setOnDismissListener(DismissListener onDismissListener) {
        mOnDismissListener = onDismissListener;
    }

    DismissListener mOnDismissListener;

    private void onDeselect() {
        deselectAnimation.prepare();
        startAnimation(deselectAnimation);

        if (mOnDismissListener != null)
            mOnDismissListener.onDismiss();

    }
```

In activity

```
rvl.setOnDismissListener(new ReactionView.DismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(int selectedIndex) {
        root.removeView(rvl);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Zain, I tried your first way and its working.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this with a listener.

In your ReactionView class add :

```
interface ReactionListener{

    public void onReactionClicked();
}
```

Then add to the constructor of `ReactionView` `(Context context, ReactionListener: listener)`. I assume you want to hide this view when the user is clicking on an emoji, so where you set click listener for that, also call `listener.onReactionClicked()`

Then in your adapter create the listener object and remove the view:

```
private ReactionListener reactionListener = new ReactionView.ReactionListener(){
    @override 
    public void onReactionClicked(){
       root.removeView(rvl);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Miruna I tried what you have suggested, I added the ReactionListener in my ReactionView Class and also created  the constructor like this
`public ReactionView(Context context, ReactionListener listener) { super(context);this.listener = listener;init();}`
In my Adapter class I am implementing like this
`final ReactionView rvl = new ReactionView( mContext, new ReactionView.ReactionListener() {@Overridepublic void onReactionClicked() {
root.removeView( rvl );}} );root.addView(rvl);`
but it is giving me the error Variable 'vrl` might not have been initialized

Comment: if I try to remove final from declaration it again gives me error `Variable vrl is accessed within inner class, needs to be declared final`

can you suggest what to do